# HAProxy using even/odd or regex in uri

Tags: regex, uri, haproxy

I would like to set some rules about query parameter URI, based on *odd/even* for example:

```
$ curl -I 'localhost:10001/test/?id=1' #  use one backend
$ curl -I 'localhost:10001/test/?id=2' #  user another back-end
```

I can get the id number using an ACL like:

```
acl has_id  urlp(id) -m bool
```

But I can't use `even` function, I didn't understand the docs.

- http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#7.3.1-odd

Also, I'm able to compare the id with some number, like this:

```
acl has_id  urlp(id) -m int ge 666
```

But can't see if is odd or even.

I also tried to use `path_reg` but this not works with uri, only with path.

Comment: Possibly `urlp(id),even -m bool`.  Converters are preceded by their first parameter.

Comment: Michael, close enough, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Worked with:

`acl is_odd urlp_val(id) odd -m found`

Using `urlp_val` the value was converted to integer \m/